# Criaçao de formularios

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

O meu problema é o seguinte:
Tenho um classe por exemplo cliente ela via possuir nome, sobrenome e cpf e uma lista de objetos da classe endereco. A classe de endereco so vai ter o campo logradouro e cidade.
Minha duvida é a seguinte como crio um formulario para preencher os dados do cliente e vou para uma outra tela para inserir os enderecos e depois envio com apenas 1 submit todos esses dados? da pra aser feito com o thymeleaf ou precisa de javascript?

Comment: Javascript... Se fosse Java EE sugeriria usar um EJB Stateful (ou bean FlowScoped). Pra você fazer isto terá que manter o estado do formulário no backend de alguma forma (que sobreviva a mudança de página, e.g outro request). Não tenho mta experiência com spring-boot, mas acredito q sua melhor saída seja javascript nesse caso.

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada nesse site tbm, talvez te ajude: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handling-multipage-forms-with-abstractwizardformcontroller/

Comment: Adicione na sua pergunta evidencias do código para melhor entender o problema apresentando. Uma dica.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode esta usando um tab dentro de um form.
Veja exemplo abaixo com bootstrap

```
       <div class="tab-content">

            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabela1">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group  col-lg-12">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="tabela2">
                <div class="row">

                </div>

                <div class="row">

                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
```